# What is `"dev" true` in package-lock.json for?

Tags: npm, package.json

What does `"dev" true` means in `package-lock.json` file?

In my case it is automatically updated when I perform `npm` operations.

How can we remove it?

Comment: There are a lot of mysteries about `package-lock.json`. The hash sometimes has a longer version and a shorter version, besides this `dev` thing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

So answering your first question, `"dev": true` in `package-lock.json` means this dependency won't be installed by `npm install`/`npm ci` when running in `production` mode.

Having dependencies used only for local development environment marked with `"dev": true` and then using `--production` in your CI  might save you some build time.

From documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#description:

> By default, `npm install` will install all modules listed as
>   dependencies in `package.json`.
>
> With the `--production` flag (or when the `NODE_ENV` environment
>   variable is set to `production`), npm will not install modules listed
>   in `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 17):

I think this paragraph tries to illustrate how the package dependency's dev: true is assigned.

- Directly development dependency -> `dev: true`
- With only indirect development dependency -> `dev: true`
- Directly development dependency however
  it also has indirect non-develop dependency -> no `dev: true`

In other words, once a develop dependency package is indirectly dependent by a non-development package, it shall be `dev: false` and thus it will be included in the build process. The purpose of this rule is to make sure that packages needed by the non-develop package will not have `"dev: true"`.

Besides, if I install via `npm install -D <name>`, then the package will be installed as the develop package thus no `dev: true` changes may occur. However, if install via `npm install <name>`, this may remove many existing dependencies' `"dev: true"` attribute.

For example, I run `npm install -D bestzip` in my project and the result is:

- 53 dependencies with "dev": true added

Run `npm install bestzip` and the result is:

- 53 dependencies without "dev": true added
- 43 existing dependencies' "dev": true attribute are removed

Comment: Can't we just say that because a certain dependency is under `"devDependencies": {..}` in package.json, it's subdependencies will have `"dev": true` appended in case we run `npm install`

Answer (score 12):

From the npm docs at https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

> If true then this dependency is either a development dependency ONLY of the top level module or a transitive dependency of one. This is false for dependencies that are both a development dependency of the top level and a transitive dependency of a non-development dependency of the top level.

Comment: can you please explain this in simple terms?

Comment: why do we need it?

Comment: My `package-lock.json` file is constantly changing.  The only difference in most cases is the inclusion or removal of 'dev: true'!  Given its alleged purpose, I certainly am not moving dependencies between that and 'devDependencies' so fail to understand why I'm seeing this change.

Comment: Simplified version: if package added as **dev**-dependency and also used by other packages from **dev**-dependencies, then `dev: true`. If that package was required by _at least one_ package from dependencies - npm switches it `dev: false`.

Comment: A transitive dependency example would be:

If packageA relies on packageB as a `development` dependency, and packageB relies on packageC as a `development` dependency, then packageC is a transitive dependency of packageA.

Comment: @HankCa I had the same issue (`"dev": true` being constantly added and removed), and the root of the issue is because sometimes the package install was being done with `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` and, on other moments, with only `npm install`