# npm install removes "dev": true from several packages in package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

Today I pulled latest from a shared Git repository and noticed that another developer on my team added an NPM package. So I ran `npm install`, and then saw that my `package-lock.json` file had changed. When I dug into what had changed, I found that `"dev": true` had been removed from several package descriptions, for example:

```
"some-package": {
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/whatever/-/some-package-1.0.0.tgz",
  "integrity": "some-big-hash",
  "dev": true
},
```

The `"dev": true` is gone after `npm install` from several packages. Should I be concerned that NPM did this? I don't want these packages to be installed for production.

[This question about `"dev": true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51619019/27457) is somewhat related, but there isn't a good answer yet and I still want to know if I'm doing something wrong. Why is NPM removing this?

Comment: Related issue/bug reported [here](https://npm.community/t/package-lock-json-keeps-changing-between-platforms-and-runs/1129/10)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \`"dev" true\` in package-lock.json for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809490/what-is-dev-true-in-package-lock-json-for)

Answer (score 3):

Your `"dev": true` disappeared because the package became a non-dev dependency.

A package with `"dev": true` is only needed in development, not in production.

This means it is required, directly or indirectly, only via `devDependencies` and not via anything in `dependencies`.

It will not be installed if you do `npm install --production` or have `NODE_ENV=production` in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `legacy-peer-deps=true` from git config